# How do I get django-allauth to send html emails

Tags: django, django-allauth, cookiecutter-django

Cookiecutter-django uses:

- django-allauth (which needs to send registration confirmation emails)
- django-anymail configured to use mailgun.

Things are mostly working. But I can't figure out why I'm only getting plain text emails instead of HTML emails. I do have html emails defined in templates/account.

I must be missing a configuration setting someplace. But it looks like just the presense of the .html files should be enough.

So how do I get django-allauth to send html emails?

Comment: Have you also created `account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.html` ?

Comment: have you set ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE_EXTENSION to something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are only getting plain text email is because django-allauth package does not contain any HTML email templates by default.

This is mentioned on the official django-allauth documentation found at https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-email:

> The project does not contain any HTML email templates out of the box. When you do provide these yourself, note that both the text and HTML versions of the message are sent.

You need to follow the instructions listed here (https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-email) for the exact file structure + naming convention you need to use in order to create your project specific HTML templates.